# Unable to format a string in Python

Tags: python

I get `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string` for the following code:

```
 print("%s,%s,%s" % time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), (sensor.read_temperature(), (sensor.read_humidity()))
```

It should print the date/time and two variables in CSV format to the console. What's wrong with my format string?

Comment: Your code has a syntax error, as posted. Too many opening `(` parentheses for the number of closing parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only give the format string *one* argument; the other two values are a separate argument to the `print()` function.

Move the opening parenthesis:

```
print("%s,%s,%s" % (
    time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
    sensor.read_temperature(),
    sensor.read_humidity())
)
```

Now all values to be interpolated are in a single tuple, applied to the `'...' %` portion. You could just use the `print()` function here though, setting the `sep` argument to a comma:

```
print(
    time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
    sensor.read_temperature(),
    sensor.read_humidity(),
    sep=',')
```